# I want to use pywebview on tkinter. But it doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, webview, pywebview

I try to implement url to appear in a specific area in tkinter using pywebview, but an error occurs.

Source Code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import webview
import threading

def show_website():
    # Tkinter 창 생성
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Create a frame for the website display area
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Creating a Web View Window
    webview_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
    webview_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    window = webview.create_window("Web View Example", webview_frame, width=800, height=600)

    url = "https://www.example.com"
    window.load_url(url)

    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=show_website)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

If you do this, a main window fail will occur.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: File "C:\workspace\cs_ihb\test.py", line 20, in show_website
    window.load_url(url)
  File "C:\python\venv311\Lib\site-packages\webview\window.py", line 44, in wrapper
    raise WebViewException('Main window failed to start')
webview.util.WebViewException: Main window failed to start

Comment: Missing is webview.start